# Where do I ask about rhetoric?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm referring to rhetoric as [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric).

I want to ask if a certain phrase is a [rhetorical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device) recognized with some name somewhere in literature or a Wikipedia link. It's a phrase constructed of words (sic) I've seen it used in many conversations, debates, it's a language resource to convince or convey a point to an audience.
More specifically, this is the rhetorical device:

> You can say X all you want.

When X is an argument the opponent is making and the user of the device is trying to downplay it.

Comment: What kind of question do you have about rhetoric?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: Kidding aside, @Servy is on the nose: it depends on the specific question. [English.se] has serviced a number of questions on rhetoric, but, eg, wouldn't be the place to ask about how Socrates employed it in his apology (because, inconsiderately, he delivered it in Greek). Similarly, [Philosophy.se] often answers questions about formal and informal fallacies, which are studied, and often consciously employed, in certain rhetorical devices. Can you give us some examples, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Philosophy Stack Exchange accepts questions about rhetoric](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhetoric). But not every question about rhetoric is applicable to the site. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.